# How to tell if a Port is in use in Python without using Commands in the CMD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server

I am trying to write a bit of code in Python to create a basic Chat Application through a computer as a hardware "server". I am trying to write a bit of code to automate switching to a different port number if another server is active on the port number. I would think that what you would do is similar to this:

```
IP = "127.0.0.1"
availability=1
while(avalibility<=65535):
    try:
        PORT = availability
        print(PORT)
        break
    except OSError:
        availability+=1
        continue
```

When I run this code, using the print as a basis to see what is happening, and having 2 server codes running, the Port Number is the same. I am trying to have it so that if another server code is running on a port to switch it automatically so that my chat server can be completely automatic. Any tips and tricks for this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Socket in use, as per your title, or port in use, as per your actual question? If the latter, specify port 0 when you bind and the system will allocate one for you. You don't need to loop.

Comment: Port and I fixed the title for future reference in case anyone has a similar problem I had. That was exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Though I am wondering how I would see the Port Number on the Server itself? Because if port 0 is the server that is being created, how would a client connect to the server via a client-side code? Bad design on my part but oh well.

Comment: The socket isn't bound to port 0. That's just an indication to the system to allocate a real port. You discover it with `getsockname()`, whatever that means in Python.

Comment: Alright, I would just need to type server_socket.getsockname() and have that be printed to the server board to be able to see what the tuple of the IP and the Port number. *server_socket being the name of the object for my socket, will vary based on how it is typed in your own code.*